# Why does my $http put not actually send any data?

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code block:

```
app.putConfigs = function () {
    $http({
        data: app.config,
        headers: app.user.getHeaders(),
        url: '/api/Config/Put',
        method: "PUT"
    });
}
```

As far as I can see this is the same as in the angular documentation. app.config is an object.

When I check with fiddler no JSON data is being sent to the server.

Is there something wrong with the way I am using $http ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with something simple to help diagnose your problem.  See if this works:

```
$http.put('/api/config', { key: 'test' }).then(function(resp) {
  console.log(resp);
});
```

Docs ref: [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#put)

Comment: I realize now that the problem is that I am transforming the data that is sent to the server. It's no longer in JSON format. I will look into this more. Thanks